# What happens when a Parse cloud function returns a Promise?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

This is a very simple question, but I can't find an answer to it in the Parse docs, nor in StackOverflow.

If I have a Parse Cloud function, e.g.:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("someFunction", function (req, res) {
  return new Parse.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    // Do something then resolve or reject
  }
}
```

and I call it from my mobile app:

```
Parse.Cloud.run("someFunction", {})
```

What happens to the Promise returned by `Parse.Cloud.run`?

I tested this, and it appears never to resolve nor reject.  I know that the concept of a promise created on one host resolving remotely to another host is probably not possible, but I have no idea how Parse works under the hood. (And it would be super cool if it did work this way!)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens almost as you wish.  Cloud functions get passed a FunctionResponse object which implements `success()` and `error()`, so...

```
Parse.Cloud.define("someFunction", function (request, response) {
    var anyPromise = // anything that creates a promise
    // no reason to return here, the caller is opaque
    anyPromise.then(function(result) {
        response.success("this will be what Cloud.run resolves to");
    }, function(error) {
        response.error("this will be passed to the reject function of Cloud.run");
    });
});
```

The other nice thing this does is hide the network serialization for us, so...

```
response.success(anyObject);
```

will serialize any object, return it, and rebuild it as a parameter to the resolution...

```
Parse.Cloud.run("someFunction", {}).then(function(result) {
    // result == anyObject
});
```

Comment: Thanks! You mean `response.success(anyObject)`, right?

Comment: @LaneRettig, :-) yes. Edited.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. So basically it is NOT possible to return a promise directly from a cloud function. Rather, we must resolve/reject the promise and call response.success or response.error accordingly. Is my understanding accurate?